# Solver in VBA not updating

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, solver

I tried coding a mix and max solver subroutine in VBA. However, it only worked on the first try. After the second try, it is not updating both the "target cell" and the "by changing cell"

The code of the min and max solver subroutines is below. Can anyone help identify the issue? Much Thanks!

```
Sub Min()

  Application.Run "SolverReset"
 
  Application.Run "SolverOk", "Min", 2, "0", "StockPriceMin"
 
  Application.Run "SolverSolve", True
 
  Application.Run "SolverFinish"
End Sub
 
Sub Max()
 
  Application.Run "SolverReset"
  
  Application.Run "SolverOk", "Max", 1, "0", "StockPriceMax"
 
  Application.Run "SolverSolve", True
 
  Application.Run "SolverFinish"

End Sub
```

Here is the Excel screenshot. For Min, I am trying to change C12 to attain the minimum value of C20
[image]